# regex to extract first series of numbers in a string and all words after

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

Trying to write a regex that will do the following in python 2.7:

```
FOO 288-B BAR <MATCH: "288-B BAR">

BURT 69/ERNIE 96/KERMIT 287 <MATCH: "69">

53 ORANGE <MATCH: "53 ORANGE">

APPLE 457-W <MATCH: "457-W">
```

Except for "space" and '-' and '/' no other punctuation. I just want to match the first occurrence of any number and any letter/word following that is preceeded by a '-' or a "space".

I have tried:

- [`([\d]+)(-?[\w+])`](http://regexr.com/3907s)

  This misses the letters AFTER the space. Adding `\s?` doesn't go well for me.
- [`(\d+(?:(?:\-\w+)|\w)?)(.*)`](http://www.regexr.com/3907v)

  This picks up the letters but I can't seem to modify it to get rid of the stuff *after* the backslash.
- [`(\d+(?:(?:\-\w+)|\w))[^\/]*(\/*.*)`](http://regexr.com/39082)

  I'm trying to use `[]` to tackle those backslashes. This was clearly unsuccessfull.

Comment: can you show some expected output?

Comment: FYI I had a bug: it could end with a space. Fixed now, have a look. :)

Comment: Why this `BURT 69/ERNIE 96/KERMIT 287` should match just `69` rather than `69/ERNIE 96/KERMIT 287`??

Comment: @AamirAdnan '/' are the only punctuation mark I need to treat differently then the '-' and the ' '. So, basically, if I see a '/' I need to get the number before the '/' -- and ONLY that number (nothing after the '/')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you can use this, then retrieve the matches from Group 1:

```
(?im)^\D*(\d+(?:[- ][a-z ]*[a-z])?)
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tL4hU2) (please look at the capture groups in the bottom right pane).

To retrieve the matches:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"(?im)^\D*(\d+(?:[- ][a-z ]*[a-z])?)", subject):
    yournumber = match.group(1)
```

**How does it work?**

1. The `^` in `(?im)` multi-line, case-insensitive mode anchors us at the beginning of the line.
2. The `\D*` skips any non-digits
3. The `(\d+(?:[- ][a-z ]*[a-z])?)` matches, and captures to Group 1, digits optionally followed by a dash or a space and more spaces and letters, ending with a letter.

Comment: @zx81 Your expression will match only `457-W` from `APPLE 457-W3` instead of `457-W3` change `[a-z ]*[a-z]` to `[a-z0-9 ]*[a-z0-9]` to work.

Comment: @AamirAdnan Nice to hear from you. The requirements are unclear: `any letter/word following`... I have assumed he wants to end with a letter, but if he wants to allow strings such as `457-W1111` as you suggest, yes, it's an easy tweak. :) The fact that he used a `\w` word character in his tests is no symptom at this stage, since he hasn't mentioned underscores.

Comment: @ I am expecting it to end on a letter. More numbers fails the test of ONLY incl. the first series of numbers. (sorry for the clarity fail). :)